Center Set of Equations Using Align
Is it possible to center equations using align?
A simple example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &\text{a} = \frac{\text{x}}{\text{y}} \sim 1.5\times10^{-3} ,& \\
    &\text{b} = \frac{\text{y}}{\text{z}} \sim 1.5\times10^{-1} ,&\\
    &\text{c} = \frac{\text{z}}{\text{a}} \sim 1.5\times10^{-1} .&
\end{align*}
\end{document}

The equation length should not be relevant.

You can get the result you want by removing all the ampersands. But the gather environment might be better for your needs.

You're adding a second pair of columns with the trailing &, which LaTeX reserves space for. Remove it.
I changed \text{a} and the similar constructs into a, because the traditional method for typesetting variables is using italic type. If you really want upright type it should be \mathrm{a}.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% this is just to show the center
\noindent\hspace*{\fill}\smash{\vrule depth 4cm height 0cm width 0.1pt}\hspace*{\fill}


\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{x}{y} \sim 1.5\times10^{-3} , \\
b &= \frac{y}{z} \sim 1.5\times10^{-1} , \\
c &= \frac{z}{a} \sim 1.5\times10^{-1} .
\end{align*}

\end{document}

In the code, the mysterious line is just to draw a rule in the center of the type box.
Note also the position of &, so that the different widths of the left-hand sides are compensated and the equals signs are aligned.

